# bootstrap h1 and normal text alignment

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to align some normal text with h1 text. The normal text near h1 appears as a superscript. I have tried vertical-align but is not working.

Here is how it looks like:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-md-auto">
    <h1>Some big text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-md-auto">Some normal text</div>
    <div class="col col-md-auto">Some normal text</div>
    <div class="col col-md-auto">Some normal text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opr90zau/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the bootstrap [class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/utilities/flex/#align-items) `align-items-center` to vertical center align text. Add you don't need 2 rows, single row with columns work fine.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col col-md-auto">
    <h1>Some big text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-md-auto">Some normal text</div>
  <div class="col col-md-auto">Some normal text</div>
  <div class="col col-md-auto">Some normal text</div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: it is better than being aligned top, ty

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
    <div class="row">
      <div 
        <h1>Some big text</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="pull-left">
        <div>Some normal text</div>
        <div>Some normal text</div>
        <div>Some normal text</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: In bootstrap grid system, it is always suggested to have columns within rows. See #3 in the documentation. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/

Answer (score -1):

**pls try this code**

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col col-md-auto">
        <h1>Some big text</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row flex-column">
        <div class="col col-md-auto">Some normal text</div>
        <div class="col col-md-auto">Some normal text</div>
        <div class="col col-md-auto">Some normal text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```